# if i wanted to do ls on files would this suffice?

Tags: bash, grep, ls

```
 ls | grep -v "//|=/|@/||"
```

will ls then piped to a reverse grep work?
This question seems to not meet the quality standards, maybe if i write more random things
it will be a quality question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please elaborate.

Comment: I normally find that it suffices to do `ls` when doing an `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this you should explicitly add the `-F` flag.

```
ls -F | grep '...'
```

Using find would be more elegant, in my opinion:

```
find . -type f                # Recurse into subdirectories.
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f    # Do not recurse.
```